# Как пишутся названия городов, состоящие из нескольких иноязычных слов?

Tags: ономастика, заимствования, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Посоветуйте, если название города (в данном случае вымышленного) состоит из нескольких иноязычных слов, нужно ли их соединять дефисом? Яр(-)Кхал, Конре(-)Дагай и пр. Просто сразу вспоминаются города реальные, и в них стоят дефисы: Нью-Йорк, Йошкар-Ола, Улан-Батор и т. д. Есть ли специальное правило на этот счёт?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (10.12.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20310163)):

> В общих руководствах по правописанию для подобных названий правила нет. Слитное, раздельное, дефисное написание иностранных географических названий подчиняется особым правилам, их называют правилами русской передачи географических названий, и они разные для разных языков или групп языков. Но Вы правы в том, что части иностранных названий по-русски пишутся, как правило (а может быть, и всегда), через дефис. Полагаем, что на эту тенденцию нужно ориентироваться и при написании вымышленных названий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Слитное, дефисное, раздельное написание названий](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091346.html)

> Употребление личных имен и геогр. названий связано со слитным,
> дефисным и раздельным написанием. Выбор написания и употребление
> прописной буквы в этих названиях зависят и от значения имени (напр.:
> Салтыков-Щедрин — фамилия, Эрих Мария — имя), и от происхождения и
> написания слов в языке-источнике (напр.: Шарль Де Костер, Сен-Жюст,
> Пак Су Ен, Омар аш-Шариф), и от позиции в начале или в середине
> названия (напр.: Лас-Вегас, Франкфурт-на-Майне).

---

> В отношении раздельного или дефисного написания иноязычных имен нет
> единообразия. В лингвистических статьях приводятся аргументы в пользу
> дефисного написания всех многокомпонентных имен. Печать либо
> ориентируется на раздельное написание всех имен, принятое в
> энциклопедиях (напр., в БСЭ, «Большом энциклопедическом словаре»),
> либо допускает дефисное написание нек. французских имен, как правило,
> закрепленное традицией (напр.: Жан-Жак Руссо, Мария-Антуанетта), в
> соответствии с рекомендацией справочных изданий по русскому языку
> (напр.: Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по правописанию, произношению,
> литературному редактированию. М., 1994, III, § 13). *Рекомендуется
> принять одно из применяемых в печати решений и последовательно
> придерживаться его во всех изданиях.*

---

Артикли, предлоги, частицы ван, да, дас, де, дель, дер, ди, дос, дю, ла, ле, фон и т. п. в западноевропейских фамилиях и именах -

[далее по ссылке.](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091346.html)

---

Другое:

[Употребление артиклей с географическими названиями](https://www.study.ru/courses/pre-intermediate/geograficheskie-nazvaniya)

---

В приведённых Вами двух названиях *Яр(-)Кхал, Конре(-)Дагай* возможно как дефисное, так и раздельное написание.